# MySQL SUM(), COUNT() and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a particular question which is about MySQL. Please have a look at the query and the result set below:

```
SELECT `SentTo`, 
       `Read`
FROM `Emails` as t
```

```
hello@mydomain.com   | 1
--------------------------------
hello@mydomain.com   | 0
--------------------------------
hello@mydomain.com   | 1
--------------------------------
support@mydomain.com | 0
--------------------------------
support@mydomain.com | 1
--------------------------------
```

I'd like to get the count of the emails for each email, and the total Read. I will get unread by subtracting total and read on the script side, don't really need it here.

```
Email                | Total | Read
--------------------------------------
hello@mydomain.com   |   3   |   1
--------------------------------------
support@mydomain.com |   2   |   1
--------------------------------------
```

Any advice? I have tried to apply sub-queries to this but I couldn't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT `SentTo`,
       COUNT(*) Total,
       SUM(`Read`=0) 
FROM Emails
GROUP BY `SentTo`
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd3f3/2)

Comment: `SUM(Read=0)` A true Mysql solution for conditional count +1

Answer (score 1):

A 'Group by' clause can solve this problem as follows:

```
SELECT `SentTo`, COUNT(*) as totalSend, (totalSend - SUM(`Read`)) as totalUnread
FROM `Emails`  
GROUP BY `SentTo`
```

Comment: Besides the fact this isn't valid syntax, it doesn't produce the correct results if it were... First, You can't reference a column alias in the `SELECT` query like this.  Second, `COUNT(DISTINCT SentTo)` will always equal 1 -- OP is asking for `COUNT(*)`...

Answer (score 0):

Group by should give the desired result

```
SELECT sentTo,
       Sum(READ) AS TotalRead,
       Sum(CASE WHEN READ =0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS Unread
FROM Emails
GROUP BY sentTo
```

Comment: This would `SUM` the `Read` column, not `SUM` when it's equal to 0.  Also, `Read` is a reserved word in MySql and would need to be escaped.

Comment: OP wants values when read is 1, as you can see in the example where first email got 3 reads

Comment: That's the Total, which is the `COUNT(*)`. For example, hello has 3 total records, but only 1 with read=0.  This query returns hello with 2.